# Undesired background compilation of Nvidia kernel module

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, compiling, background-process

Recently, on a fresh boot, I noticed a 100% usage of my whole CPU. Quickly browsing with htop I saw 4 cc1 process compiling something, but can't know what. So I leave a script in my home to catch all the information of the process if this event happened again.

Script:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
ps -eF | grep cc1
```

So this happen again and I ran the script getting:

> ```
> root       15586   15584 76 54470 188180  3 08:38 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64->linux-gnu/9/cc1 
> -quiet -nostdinc -I ./arch/x86/include -I ./arch/x86/include/generated -I ./include -I >./arch/x86/include/uapi 
> -I ./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I ./include/uapi -I ./include/generated/uapi -I >./ubuntu/include 
> -I /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/common/inc -I >/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build 
> -I /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu 
> -MD /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_va_block.d -MQ >/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_va_block.o -D __KERNEL__ 
> -D CONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -D CC_USING_FENTRY -D __KERNEL__ -D MODULE -D NVRM -D >NV_VERSION_STRING="470.141.03" -D NV_UVM_ENABLE -D NV_SPECTRE_V2=0 
> -D NV_KERNEL_INTERFACE_LAYER -D NVIDIA_UVM_ENABLED -D NVIDIA_UNDEF_LEGACY_BIT_MACROS 
> -D Linux -D __linux__ -D MODULE -D KBUILD_BASENAME="uvm_va_block" -D >KBUILD_MODNAME="nvidia_uvm" -D __KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_nvidia_uvm 
> -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include -include ./include/linux/compiler->version.h 
> -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h 
> -MMD /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm/.uvm_va_block.o.d >/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_va_block.c 
> -quiet -dumpbase uvm_va_block.c -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 ->mno-80387 
> -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno->red-zone -mcmodel=kernel 
> -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -mfunction-return=thunk-extern >-mrecord-mcount -mfentry -mno-red-zone 
> -mcmodel=kernel -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip >/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/470.141.03/build/nvidia-uvm/uvm_va_block.o 
> -g -O2 -O2 -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -Werror=implicit-function->declaration -Werror=implicit-int 
> -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-frame-address -Wformat->truncation=0 -Wformat-overflow=0 
> -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno->main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable 
> -Wunused-const-variable=0 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno->stringop-truncation -Wno-array-bounds 
> -Wstringop-overflow=0 -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=date-time ->Werror=incompatible-pointer-types 
> -Werror=designated-init -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wall -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -Wno->format-extra-args -Wno-unused-function 
> -Wuninitialized -Werror=undef -std=gnu90 -p -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fno-common -fshort->wchar -fno-PIE -fcf-protection=none 
> -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-jump-tables -fno->delete-null-pointer-checks -fstack-protector-strong 
> -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-strict-overflow -fstack->check=no -fconserve-stack -fno-strict-aliasing 
> -fno-stack-clash-protection -fcf-protection=none -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize=shift ->fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum 
> --param allow-store-data-races=0 -fstack-protector-strong -o /tmp/ccMIQJjy.s
> ```

This shows that a kernel module from NVIDIA is getting compiled, more specific `kmod_nvidia_uvm`. This happened to me multiple times at the moment, and I have no clue of why this happens so often (I think once per reboot). If someone has any information about this I will be thankful.

**Edit:**

Comment suggest add `dkms status` output:

> ```
> nvidia, 470.141.03, 5.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
> nvidia, 470.141.03, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
> v4l2loopback, 0.12.3, 5.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
> v4l2loopback, 0.12.3, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
> virtualbox, 6.1.32, 5.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
> virtualbox, 6.1.32, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
> ```

and `tree /var/lib/dkms/` output (NVIDIA related only):

> ```
> /var/lib/dkms/
> ├── dkms_dbversion
> ├── nvidia
> │   ├── 470.141.03
> │   │   ├── 5.15.0-43-generic
> │   │   │   └── x86_64
> │   │   │       ├── log
> │   │   │       │   └── make.log
> │   │   │       └── module
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-drm.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-modeset.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-peermem.ko
> │   │   │           └── nvidia-uvm.ko
> │   │   ├── 5.15.0-46-generic
> │   │   │   └── x86_64
> │   │   │       ├── log
> │   │   │       │   └── make.log
> │   │   │       └── module
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-drm.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-modeset.ko
> │   │   │           ├── nvidia-peermem.ko
> │   │   │           └── nvidia-uvm.ko
> │   │   └── source -> /usr/src/nvidia-470.141.03
> │   ├── kernel-5.15.0-43-generic-x86_64 -> 470.141.03/5.15.0-43 >generic/x86_64
> │   └── kernel-5.15.0-46-generic-x86_64 -> 470.141.03/5.15.0-46 >generic/x86_64
> ```

Kernel used:

> ```
> Linux version 5.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-007) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022
> ```

Comment: It's strange, because the compilation should take place only during installation of a new version of Nvidia driver, or installation of a new version of kernel. Maybe something went wrong for you during the last upgrade of these components?

Comment: Please add `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: Added `dkms status` output. Thanks for your comment

Comment: There is at least two (510, 515) newer nvidia driver packages available under "Software and updates" > Additional drivers  (Hit "Super/Win" key and begin typing Software... and you will find the pinkish icon to click). Maybe just try switching to see if that remedies the issues?

Comment: Nothing suspicious. Please check with `tree /var/lib/dkms/` if there is a leftover from an older kernel or nvidia package.

Comment: Added `tree /var/lib/dkms/` output. Again, thanks for the comment.

Comment: I don't want to update the driver until know why this is happening or when I allowed NVIDIA drivers to compile without asking... But thanks for the comments.

Comment: Sorry forgot. please can you share `cat /proc/version` ? i have another kernel on my system.

Comment: No problem, added asked information, thanks!